# Find a specific cell based on a dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to the cell next to a name selected in a dropdown which that the total time listed.  I thought it might be something like `=SUMIF(E4,'Refined Data'!A:A,'Refined Data'!B:B)` but that is not working.
The desired out come would be if you select Person 1 in the dropdown, it would say 0:00:54 in cell E6 since that is the cell next to person 1 in `Refined Data` and Person 2 in the dropdown would then cause E6 to say 2:10:31.  Here is an [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QfkkccEju725pQtUcoQpY_38lJxb1BJIrTb5FJ5Uv5I/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this formula below on cell E6 on your "Dashboard" sheet:

=vlookup(E4,'Refined Data'!A1:B100, 2)

This should work fine

Answer (score 1):

```
=VLOOKUP(E4,'Refined Data'!A1:B100, 2, 0)
```

Here’s what the VLOOKUP formula looks like:

```
VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index, [is_sorted])
```

**search_key** – This is the value or item you’re looking for. For example, in the case of the restaurant, it would be burger or pizza.

**range** – this is the range to be used in the Vlookup function. The left-most column of this range would be searched for the search_key.

**index** – this is the column number from where you want to get the result. The first column in the range is 1, the second column is 2, and so on. Note that this value should be between 1 and the total number of columns. If not, then it would return a #VALUE! Error.

**is_sorted** – [TRUE by default] – in this argument, you can specify whether you’re looking for an exact match or an approximate match. You can use FALSE for exact match and TRUE for an approximate match. When you use TRUE, the list needs to be sorted in an ascending     If you don’t specify a value here, it takes TRUE as default.

**Dummies**

[image]